# Establish connection between parent and child class

Tags: architectural-patterns

Assume you have two classes, a `Manager` who holds a set of `Client`s and the `Client` holds a backreference to the `Manager`.

```
class Manager {
public:
    void addClient(Client* client) {
        m_clients.push_back(client);
        client->setManager(this);
    }
private:
    std::list<Client*> m_clients;
};

class Client {
public:
    void setManager(Manager* manager) {
        m_manager = manager;
    }

private:
    Manager* m_manager;
};
```

The confusing, probably even dangerous feature of this API is that Client exposes a setManager() method that can be called by anyone, yet should only be called by the Manager::addClient() method.

`assert(manager->hasClient(this))` in setManager() would prevent wrong calling at runtime, however I would prefer a solution that doesn't allow the user to call methods he isn't supposed to call.

What would be common solution? I don't

- want to use `friend` to expose all of Clients members to Manager so that he can establish the binary connection in `addChild()`
- want both classes to share some kind of Composite base class. They should remain unrelated inheritancewise.

Comment: You should change the question to `A solution that doesn't allow the user to call methods he isn't supposed to call`. Have a look at Facade, Interface, Proxy, Adaptor, Bridge. I would also say you can name the method `do_never_call_me_unless_you_know_what_for_add_client`

Comment: Could you simply check in `setManager()` whether `m_manager` has already been set?

Answer (score 1):

One fairly standard approach would be to make `Client::setManager` protected and declare `Manager::addClient` as a [friend function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/105766/9457) in `Client`. This will allow `Manager::addClient` access to all of `Client`'s private and protected members, not just `Client::setManager`, but is more encapsulated overall than a public `Client::setManager`.

See also:

- [Specify a class member function as a friend of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10546391/90527)
- [What is the use-case to use C++ friend class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/68854/9457)
- [Should I use friend classes in C++ to allow access to hidden members?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/132403/9457)
- [When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17434/90527)
- [How does the friend keyword (Class/Function) break encapsulation in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093618/90527)